# Need script to analyze process dump file (windows)

Tags: windows, dump

I have a program written in c++, it's compiled with Visual Studio.

I have a mini dump file of a running process (process generates it using winapi MiniDumpWriteDump function).

I also have several memory addresses - they should correspond to addresses of my c++ functions/methods.

I also have *.pdb file - debug information generated by Visual Studio during compilation of my program.

Now I need to find out which functions correspond to the addresses.

Question 1: Do I have enough data? Is minidump, *.pdb file and address is enough to find out function name (and it's location in source code)?

Question 2: I need to automate this process. I will have to write a script (hope it will be a python script) which will do the job. Can anyone suggest appropriate python tools?

(Originally I posted this question on stackoverflow, but looks like it's better suited here)

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do the whole thing yourself, you need to use the [Debugger Engine APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540534), in particular [`OpenDumpFile` and friends](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff542783). If you only need to automate it but no particular requirements for programming it on your own, I would suggest just using windbg with some scripts (maybe PyKd framework).